# Search within results using haystack (django) on solr

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'm trying to search within a previous search on my site.

It would be like "sky", and then after getting the results, I'd hit the radio button for 'Search within results'. Then I would type in "blue" (assuming the search bar is now empty). Thus, I would search on "sky blue".

I've been looking around quite a bit for solutions to this, but nothing seems to have been posted in this explicivity.

I'm passing the form to a custom form, but I've been unable to access the radio box. I would LIKE to just save the original query, and then if I've selected to search within, I would just make an append.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean using a checkbox?  Assuming you are clearing your search field after a form request. I'm not sure how much of the django form you are using but at a basic level, after an initial search, you can push the value from the view to the template in its own variable:

```
initial_keyword = 'sky'  # default to empty if none entered
```

In the template, insert the following within your html form tags:

```
<input type="hidden" name="initial_keyword" value="{{ initial_keyword }}" />
```

Check the values of `request.GET`, you should see `initial_keyword` and maybe your checkbox.  From there, if checkbox is checked, combine `initial_keyword` and the newly entered value.

Comment: Yep that worked. I was getting bogged down in my SearchForm class. But, going down the rabbit hole and creating the other variable worked great! Thanks.

Comment: In the end, because I'm using haystack w/SOLR, it is a little more involved. However, your idea is on the right track. I solved it by, yes, creating that variable, but there was no need to keep it hidden. As far as the clearing goes, that's some simple JavaScript (which I had to learn for this problem!).
Thanks for responding, though!